# Rust Patterns: Await-able streams?

Tags: rust, stream, generator, rust-tokio

What is the proper way to structure a Rust program for the following common use case?

###### Use Case

I have a process that queries servers for data. It's complicated: it queries several servers and interleaves streams from them. The total amount of data is too big for memory. I'd like to represent the result of that process as some kind of data structure that can be await-ed every time there is a new token from the possibly interleaved streams.

What is the proper Rust/tokio data structure to use?

As an example, in Python/JavaScript this could be an asynchronous generator.

```rust
fn query_data(...) -> ? {
    // query servers
}

let stream = query_data(...);
async for token in stream {
    // process token
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/streams?

Comment: I can't write a full answer, but I know the Tokio crate has [async methods](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.19.2/tokio/io/index.html#asyncread-and-asyncwrite) for streams, and [Rust generators exist as an unstable feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/generators.html), and it sounds like you'll need some combination of those. Maybe these links can help get you going, at least.

Comment: This is exactly what [`select!()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/macro.select.html) is for :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could just keep an array of streams and keep polling them over and over, pausing to process each new token.

Comment: Can you give more concrete code? This question is pretty broad.

Comment: Or [`select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.21/futures/future/fn.select_all.html) if the list of streams is not known at compile-time.

Comment: @Coder-256 `select` only works until one of the streams is closed, then it will either panic or continuously return `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `StreamMap` from the `tokio-stream` extension crate:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use tokio::time::sleep;
use tokio_stream::{wrappers::ReceiverStream, Stream, StreamExt, StreamMap};

fn create_stream(name: &'static str, delay_millis: u64) -> impl Stream<Item = String> {
    let (sender, receiver) = tokio::sync::mpsc::channel(10);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        for i in 0..5 {
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(delay_millis)).await;
            sender.send(format!("{}-{}", name, i)).await.unwrap();
        }
    });

    let receiver_stream: ReceiverStream<String> = receiver.into();
    receiver_stream
}

fn combine_streams<T>(stream_a: T, stream_b: T) -> impl Stream<Item = (&'static str, T::Item)>
where
    T: Stream + Unpin,
{
    let mut map = StreamMap::new();
    map.insert("a", stream_a);
    map.insert("b", stream_b);
    map
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let stream_a = create_stream("A", 200);
    let stream_b = create_stream("B", 277);

    let mut combined = combine_streams(stream_a, stream_b);

    while let Some((origin, packet)) = combined.next().await {
        println!("Received from {origin}: {packet}");
    }
}
```

```
Received from a: A-0
Received from b: B-0
Received from a: A-1
Received from b: B-1
Received from a: A-2
Received from a: A-3
Received from b: B-2
Received from a: A-4
Received from b: B-3
Received from b: B-4
```

Comment: I'm trying to make the stream be returned from the function, not passed as a separate argument. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean, both `create_stream` and `combine_streams` do return a stream from the function. Would you describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You're quite and I'm wrong: that's my mistake.